# HTMLUnit input.click() not returning the site which the click should have made load

Tags: java, html, click, htmlunit

I'm trying to make a bot fill out a form randomly with HTMLUnit.
What I've got so far:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    client.getOptions().setTimeout(60000);
    client.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    client.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);

    client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
```

The last line is supposed to make AJAX work in the background, the rest is simple Browser config.

I've written a method to correctly perform a click to a DOMElement, with logging and proper waiting for execution in the background:

```
public static HtmlPage clickCorrectly(DomElement e, WebClient client) throws IOException {

    Main_Win.log("-------------------------------------");
    Main_Win.log("Clicking correctly: " + e);
    Main_Win.log("Background JS: " + client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30000));
    Main_Win.log("Click return: " + e.click());
    Main_Win.log("Background JS: " + client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30000));
    WebWindow tmpWebWindow = client.getCurrentWindow();
    Main_Win.log("Current Window: " + tmpWebWindow);
    Main_Win.log("Returning Enclosed Page: " + tmpWebWindow.getEnclosedPage());
    Main_Win.log("Parent Page: " + tmpWebWindow.getParentWindow());
    Main_Win.log("Top level Page: " + tmpWebWindow.getTopWindow());
    Main_Win.log("-------------------------------------");
    return (HtmlPage) tmpWebWindow.getEnclosedPage(); 
}
```

This is working great for my login process. I click the login button, type my credentials and then submit it. The page stays the same. So the click doesn't change the object behind the `page` variable. Later on I'm trying to click a button which is actually an anchor tag:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary participate-link" data-id="116582" href="javascript:;" onclick="participateSurvey(116582, 'https://www.soscisurvey.de/SprachassistentenG3B/', '')">Jetzt teilnehmen</a>
```

I'm getting the anchor element via a XPath:

```
page.getByXPath("//a[@class='btn btn-primary participate-link']")
```

and then I'm casting it to the proper element:

```
HtmlAnchor a = (HtmlAnchor) o;
```

later I'm calling the click like this:

```
clickCorrectly(a, client)
```

This is working perfectly fine. I'm recieving the page which loads in my browser when I do this manually by hand in Firefox.

Now coming to my problem:

```
List<DomNode> elements = new ArrayList<DomNode>();
        elements.addAll(page.getElementsByTagName("input"));
        elements.addAll(page.getElementsByTagName("button"));
```

These are giving me all elements I want to handle. I'm checking for 3 cases:

1. The `DomNode` is an `<input>` with the type Atribute `"submit"`
2. The `DomNode` is an `<input>` with the type Atribute `"button"`
3. The `DomNode` is a `<button>`

   ```
   if(i.getTypeAttribute().equalsIgnoreCase("submit")) {

           if(i.toString().contains("weiter") || i.toString().contains("Weiter")){

               Main_Win.log("LOGGING BUTTON RETURN PAGE--------");
               Main_Win.log("Page before click: " + page);
               page = Main.clickCorrectly(i, client);
               Main_Win.log("Page after click: " + page);
               Main_Win.log("END LOGGING BUTTON RETURN PAGE--------");

               return true;
           }
       }
   ```

"Weiter" is german for "continue". I'm checking like this for all 3 cases. What happens now is more clear when you take a look at the log:

[image]

As you can see, the before and after page are different.
Theoretically the Browser should now handle a different page, since i set the page variable to the return value of the click.
In the next iteration in my loop the previous URL gets handeled, not the one I achieved throgh clicking, event though I set page to it and the loop reacquires all the page content every time the loop cycles. I can't figure out why that happens.
Here is the whole class for better understanding:

https://pastebin.com/1wxdwUKS

The final goal is to get the last page of the survey, where no continue button is present.
Sry for the long post and thanks for your time!

Comment: So after a lot of debugging I found out, that the ID of the page variable is actually resetting after the return is given. So it may be that a HTMLPage is not given by reference... Which is kind of strange, because it is an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually the point with the reference was the problem. For whatever reason the HtmlPage OBJECT was not passed by reference... I have no idea why, but that did cost a ton of my lifetime. I'll leave this up for others who have the same issue.

I solved it by just passing it to a global static variable:

```
public static HtmlPage page = null;
```

and just copying it once at start:

```
AutoAnswer.page = pageCPY;
```

Hope this will once save someone a lot of time :D
Thanks for reading!